# Need more elaboration regarding, --save-dev

Tags: npm, gulp

I see `--save-dev` mentioned in Gulp tutorials and from what I see, it adds npm functionality to a project's dependency.

But what does that mean exactly? Is that significant when the project gets moved from one machine to another?

Thank you for any clarification of `--save-dev` importance with Gulp.

Answer (score 3):

In a `npm` package there 2 types of dependencies: the production ones and the development ones.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
     // .. a list of production dependencies
     // i.e. angular or express
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     // .. a list of dependencies strictly needed only in development mode
     // i.e. gulp or grunt
  }
}
```

You need the former to make the application run in production. The latter are used when in development mode, so everything around the build system, minification, etc...

Gulp, as a building system, is more a `devDependency` by nature, than a production dependency. This is why you often find in Gulp/Gulp plugins tutorials things are:

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp
```

That `--save-dev` flag will put the installed dependency you're asking in the `devDependencies` bucket while using `--save` sets the dependency in the `dependencies` (production) one.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what the differences between production and development modes are? In other words, the development version can be moved around one machine to another safely?